# Slicing Dataframe according to other Dataframe, performing calculations based on those slices

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

Given are 2 dataframes.
Lets say one includes 100,000 rows, and the other one 100 rows.
The shorter df provides in each row, a start and end time that corresponds to index on the larger df.
First, I need to slice the first one according to those 100 different time stamps given in the second one.
After that, I have to apply a function to those rows inside the time stamps, but only those, not the ones outside a timestamp.
Then, I have to calculate the difference between the actual values and the ones that resulted from the function.
Currently, I am using iterrows, but this is obviously a really slow solution.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.